# easy way to send a json array in a single variable to a view codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php-7

when I tried to access to my json result with my index called `$this->data['fields'] = $menu;` I noticed of something that I have to send all my data with `$this->data`, but at the moment when I want to display some values from that array I cant because it´s a bad way to access in my case. however if I use my session variable  `$data = $this->session->userdata('log');` I can do it proprely. So I think the best way to send my array json is like this `$variable = $menu` but I want an index to access  easily, but I dont know how to add it without use `$this->data['fields'] = $menu;` is there any other way? how can i fix it? I want to send my variable like this `$this->load->view('menu/menu',$data);`

modules

```
public function getModules(){
    if($this->session->userdata('log')){
        $data = $this->session->userdata('log');
        $menu = array();
        $seccions = $this->module->get_rows();
        foreach ($seccions as $index => $seccion){
           $modules = $this->module->query("SELECT CONCAT('".$seccion['id']."',storelte_modulo.id) AS id,CONCAT('".base_url('assets/img/sidebar')."','/',storelte_modulo.icon) as icon, storelte_modulo.modulo AS value,storelte_modulo.seccion_id,CONCAT('".base_url()."',storelte_modulo.url) AS  url FROM storelte_modulo INNER JOIN storelte_modulo_perfil ON  storelte_modulo_perfil.modulo_id = storelte_modulo.id WHERE seccion_id = $seccion[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.perfiles_id = $data[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.STATUS = 1");
            $seccions[$index]['data']= $modules;
            if (!count($seccions[$index]['data']))
                unset($seccions[$index]);
        }
        foreach ($seccions as $item)
            array_push($menu,$item);
      $this->data['fields'] = $menu;
      $this->load->view('menu/menu',$this->data);
    }
}
```

html

```
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
  <section class="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
     <li class="treeview">
         <?php foreach ($fields as $session) : ?>
           //code
         <?php endforeach ?>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</aside>
```

Comment: Change `$this->load->view('menu/menu',$data);` to `$this->load->view('menu/menu',$this->data);`. Also set other variables properly e.g. `$this->data['log'] = $this->session->userdata('log');`.

Comment: is it other way to add fields without use after $this->data because I cant acces on my view ? how can I access to my index on my view because If I do echo $fields I cant? how can i do it? I'm getting consufed on how can I do it somebody help me

Comment: Do you use `$this->data` variable somewhere else except controller an view files above?

Comment: I dont use it  just in controller, but when I want to back to my home_view and it has <?php $this->load->view('menu/menu'); ?> I dont know how to put it back again to my home_view.. it's kind of mutiples views –